# DataGridView en visual studio

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo eliminación sencilla y eliminación múltiple, y si me elimina en la base de datos pero me sale error en visual studio, el error es el siguiente:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
>
> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get devolvió null.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
       foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataUser.Rows)
            {
                if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    Conexion.ConnectionString = Cadenaconexion;

                    Conexion.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete from socios where correo = '" + item.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", Conexion);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Conexion.Close();


                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Elementos eliminados con exito");
            dataUser.Rows.Clear();
            button2_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Asegurese de quien desea eliminar");
        }
```

Comment: Comparte un poco te codigo, no sabemos ni como intentas hacer la eliminacion.

Comment: te juro que iba a poner codigo pero stack no me dejo; voy a intentar ponerlo en un comentario, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Debe existir un tab de 4 espacios para que lo reconosca como codigo, no lo pongas como comentario, edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, Shassain.

Comment: El error me lo marca en el if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))

Comment: Verifica si existe algún valor en `item.Cells[0]` usa un tryParse en lugar de un Parse, te dará más control

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de un error clásico, tienes valores `null` en el dato que recoges. Lo más óptimo es no permitir que eso ocurra. Al rellenar el DataGrid, pasas los `null` a `false` y se terminó el problema.

Si decides que no te gusta la solución, en la sentencia donde te da el error, compruebas que no sea `null` y en caso que lo sea, decides pasarlo a `false`, sería algo asi

```
if (bool.Parse(IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Cells[0].Value).ToString, "false", item.Cells[0].Value).ToString()))
```